# Need to change FromEmail String when sending Email through SMTPClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient

My Email Sending Code

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("mailer@abc.com", "xyz@hotmail.com", "testing email", "to check from email label text");
    SmtpClient smpt = new SmtpClient();
    smpt.Send(msg);
```

When email open by xyz@hotmail.com user, In the from email, its mentioned mailer@abc.com where as I need to show like **Abc Corporation [abc@nextech.pk]**

How can I change from Email address label

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a MailAddress with the real name and email address, then supply that to the MailMessage.

From MSDN ([From property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from.aspx) for MailMessage).

```
  MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
  MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton");
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it will showing like  Nextech Corporation [mailto:mailer@nexapps.com] (mailer@nexapps.com)  but I need  Nextech Corporation [mailto:mailer@nexapps.com]

Comment: Now I have passed the real EmailAddress, Always when I post these kinds of thing I prefer to post dummy, just for understanding

Answer (score 1):

Use the DisplayName

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
m.From = new MailAddress("mail@mailserver.com", "My Mail");
```